# How to run all unique Junit tests in a given package?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit4

If I right click on a package and run all tests it will run all the JUnit tests it finds in the package, however it will also run suites so you can multiple of the same tests running.

How can I run only JUnit tests and not suites? or only run the same test once?

Comment: Not sure if there is a special function, but you can select them with a regular expression, so make sure you name them different.

Comment: @eckes could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: Not sure about stand alone runner, but Maven Surefire has a `<include>%regex[.*[Cat|Dog].*Test.*]</include>` setting.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Eclipse doesn't have any mechanism of selecting only tests and not suites. The solution I arrived is to have a `testsuites` source folder where I save the test suites. I use `tests` source folder to keep individual test cases.